# Jenkins SonarQube Integration Failed

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube

Im trying to integrate SonarQube with Jenkins. Below are the steps I have done

1. Installed the plugin 'SonarQube Scanner for Jenkins'
2. Configured the system with SonarQube version as 5.2 and without any credentials
3. Enabled automatic installation of SolarQuber version 2.6.1 through Jenkins->Global Tool Configuration
4. Enabled the SonarQube in build process.

Getting below error. Not sure whats happening. I searched through in internet, Everyone mentioned that above four steps. Am I missing anything, Please note that port number 9000 is enabled. Please help me to fix it

```
INFO: SonarQube Scanner 2.6.1
INFO: Java 1.8.0_45 Oracle Corporation (64-bit)
INFO: Linux 3.13.0-91-generic amd64
INFO: Error stacktraces are turned on.
INFO: User cache: /var/lib/jenkins/.sonar/cache
ERROR: SonarQube server [http://localhost:9000] can not be reached
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: Total time: 0.216s
INFO: Final Memory: 3M/121M
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR: Error during SonarQube Scanner execution
org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.ScannerException: Unable to execute SonarQube
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherFactory$1.run(IsolatedLauncherFactory.java:84)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherFactory$1.run(IsolatedLauncherFactory.java:71)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherFactory.createLauncher(IsolatedLauncherFactory.java:71)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherFactory.createLauncher(IsolatedLauncherFactory.java:67)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.doStart(EmbeddedScanner.java:218)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.start(EmbeddedScanner.java:156)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.execute(Main.java:70)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.main(Main.java:60)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fail to download libraries from server
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.Jars.downloadFiles(Jars.java:93)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.Jars.download(Jars.java:70)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.JarDownloader.download(JarDownloader.java:39)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherFactory$1.run(IsolatedLauncherFactory.java:75)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:345)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okhttp.internal.Platform.connectSocket(Platform.java:101)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okhttp.Connection.connectSocket(Connection.java:198)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:172)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okhttp.Connection.connectAndSetOwner(Connection.java:358)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okhttp.OkHttpClient$1.connectAndSetOwner(OkHttpClient.java:117)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:329)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:246)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okhttp.Call.getResponse(Call.java:276)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okhttp.Call$ApplicationInterceptorChain.proceed(Call.java:234)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okhttp.Call.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(Call.java:196)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okhttp.Call.execute(Call.java:79)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.ServerConnection.callUrl(ServerConnection.java:114)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.ServerConnection.downloadString(ServerConnection.java:99)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.Jars.downloadFiles(Jars.java:78)
    ... 11 more
```

Comment: is your sonarqube server running ? ERROR: SonarQube server [http://localhost:9000] can not be reached

Comment: The question is if you are running Jenkins (and may be Sonar) from docker. If yes, then you should start using docker-compose to start both and use common network for the services with a bridge type. Then you could reach SonarQube server from Jenkins using ``http://sonar-service-name:9000``

Answer (score 0):

```
 ERROR: SonarQube server [http://localhost:9000] can not be reached
```

seems like your server is not reachable by jenkins. This can be related to a blocked port, or your Sonarqube-server is even running on another host.

If Sonarqube-Server is running on a different host, you need to adapt your settings for the plugin:

- either globally "Manage jenkins" [sonarQube settings for Jenkins](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TsPQR.png) and add the url
- or directly add at the job with the sonar property

  ```
  sonar.host.url=<your url>
  ```